# Plot a quad face in Octave

Tags: plot, octave, mesh

I have the coordinates (X,Y **and** Z)  of 4 points, (not necessarily lying on the same plane and not necessarily a rectangle!) and I want to plot this quad face in octave.

I used the following plot function

plot([x1 x2 x3 x4], [y1 y2 y3 y4], [z1 z2 z3 z4], '-')

but it didn't work.

I'd like to have as a result, not a wireframe plot (i.e. only the edges plotted) but the whole surface.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Edit: I edited my question, because I'd like to know if it is possible to achieve a contour "less continuous" (see following images).

The result I get is the following image.[Contour continuous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgLQc.png)

I'd like instead to get a less continuous contour, in which I can clearly see the boundaries between the different coloured parts (see following image).

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvUuY.png)

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! Please provide a [mcve]! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`patch`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) is your friend

```
patch([x1 x2 x3 x4], [y1 y2 y3 y4], [z1 z2 z3 z4], 'red')
```

Comment: Thanks Ander! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: @Stefano consider accepting the answer as valid then!